# How to deal with scroll-snap bug(?) in Firefox?

Tags: css, firefox, scroll, cross-browser, scroll-snap

## Demonstration

- [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3c49qez1/)
- [YouTube demonstration of bug(?)](https://youtu.be/LzncbRONy5E)

### JSFiddle Code

#### HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
  <title>Why doesn't this work right in Firefox?</title>
</head>
<body>
  <section>
    <div><h1>1</h1></div>
    <div><h1>2</h1></div>
    <div><h1>3</h1></div>
    <div><h1>4</h1></div>
    <div><h1>5</h1></div>
  </section>
</body>
```

#### CSS

```
section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}

div {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  scroll-snap-stop: always;
  scroll-snap-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

h1 {
  line-height: 100vh;
  font-size: 100vh;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

div:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-color: #FF0000;
}

div:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-color: #00FF00;
}

div:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-color: #0000FF;
}

div:nth-of-type(4) {
  background-color: #00FFFF;
}

div:nth-of-type(5) {
  background-color: #FF00FF;
}
```

## Problem Description

I have been trying to implement a simple scroll-snapping slideshow, but no matter what I have tried to do Firefox always eventually starts slowing down and stopping mid-transition, scrolling far more slowly than if scroll-snap were disabled.

Firefox for Android has similarly poor performance. Although it doesn't stop mid-transition on Android, it does sometimes take two swipes for it to even respond at all.

I have searched SO questions regarding this, but haven't found any that quite describe what I'm experiencing. That makes me think it may be a problem that is specific to my hardware rather than Firefox, but it is still a problem that only occurs in Firefox and not in Chrome.

I tried to investigate with the performance analyzer

## Environment

- Dell XPS-15 9560

  - Linux Mint 21.2 (Cinnamon 64 bit)
  - Also experienced in Windows 11 on the same machine

    - No longer installed, so I can't get version information.
    - Firefox Version 116.0.2 (64 bit)
- Samsung Galaxy S21 5G

  - Android 13
  - Firefox 116.2.0

## Performance Analysis Output

Nothing in these two instances of jank that I zoomed in on seems to be remarkable, but maybe eyes more experienced than mine can see what's up. This is from a different run than is shown in the YouTube link, but the behavior is the same.

### Scrolling Down

[image: Janky transition from 4 to 5 (scrolling down)]

### Scrolling Up

[image: Janky transition from 2 to 1 (scrolling up)]

Comment: I have filed a report on Bugzilla, but I seriously doubt that I'm the first person to notice this. I just can't find the right combination of words to find any mention of it by searching.